need help generating bootstrap 5 utilities
I'm working in a company that wants to create their own utility classes and I have to create the setup to make it work.
Here is a list of relevant details

All of these imports are what the company has already been working with, at the end I added a small piece of code that should generate classes such as test-25, it however does not
The css compiles with no errors, but my utility code is nowhere to be seen in the css output.
I added styles to test if the sass is not being imported correctly and  for instance { background: red } will indeed make the background red, but the utility class below is stripped away from the compiled css.


This is the code im working with:

// Bootstrap SCSS

// 1. Include functions first (so you can manipulate colors, SVGs, calc, etc)
@import 'bootstrap/scss/functions';

// 2. Include remainder of required Bootstrap stylesheets
@import './variables';

// 3. Include any default variable overrides here
@import '../custom';

// 4. Include any default map overrides here

// 5. Include remainder of required parts
@import 'bootstrap/scss/maps';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/mixins';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/root';

// 5. Custom mixins
@import './mixins/forms';

// 6. Optionally include any other parts as needed
@import 'bootstrap/scss/utilities';
@import './reboot'; // evi
@import 'bootstrap/scss/type';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/images';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/containers';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/grid';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/tables';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/forms/floating-labels';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/forms/form-check';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/forms/form-control';
@import './forms/form-range'; // evi
@import 'bootstrap/scss/forms/form-select';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/forms/form-text';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/forms/input-group';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/forms/labels';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/forms/validation';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/buttons';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/transitions';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/dropdown';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/button-group';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/nav';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/navbar';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/card';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/accordion';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/breadcrumb';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/pagination';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/badge';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/alert';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/progress';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/list-group';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/close';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/toasts';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/modal';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/tooltip';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/popover';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/carousel';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/spinners';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/offcanvas';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/placeholders';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/helpers';

// my code: 

$utilities: map-merge(
    $utilities, (
    "test": (
      property: opacity,
      values: (
        0: 0,
        25:.25,
        50:.5,
        75:.75,
        100: 1,
      )
    )
  )
);



// 7. Optionally include utilities API last to generate classes based on the Sass map in `_utilities.scss`
@import 'bootstrap/scss/utilities/api';


the _utilities.scss has hundreds of examples that you can copy and paste, looking at these, I found that it was necessary to have the class attribute for it to work:
This is what a working version of my code now looks like:
$newUtilities: map-merge(
    $utilities, (
    "test": (
      property: opacity,
      class: test,
      values: (
        0: 0,
        25:.25,
        50:.5,
        75:.75,
        100: 1,
      )
    )
  )
);

$utilities: map-merge($utilities, $newUtilities);

now classes such as test-25 work indeed
